# Joint PDF inequality probability

Tags: probability

Let $X$ and $Y$ be continuous random variables with the joint probability density function: $f(x, y) = k(6 − x − y)$ for $0 < x < 2,\ 2 < y < 4$, and zero otherwise.

I know how to find k, but part b of the question says:

Calculate $P(X < 1, Y < 3.5)$

How would I do this? Would I solve the double integral of k(6-x-y) between -infinity < x < 1 and -infinity < y < 3.5?

$$\int_{-\infty}^{3.5}\int_{-\infty}^1 k(6-x-y)\ dxdy$$

Comment: yes that is correct, $0 \lt x \lt 1, 2 \lt y \lt 3.5$

Comment: whereas " $-\infty< x < 1$ and $-\infty < y < 3.5$" is not correct...

Comment: Why is that correct?
Okay thank you. What about P(X+Y < 4)?

Comment: The domain of the integral is within the domain of non-zero values for the pdf.

Comment: For your second question $\int\limits_0^2\int\limits_2^{4-x}f(x,y)dydx$.

Comment: The support is an important feature of a pdf.   Always keep it in mind.

Comment: Thank you. How can 4-x be a limit? What does "support" mean?